# stop_server(@signature) is not closing port : EventMachine :Ruby

Tags: eventmachine, ruby-1.9.3

I am workng on the eventmachine . And needs to restart the servers with port in loop .

I am trying to stop the servers with the code `stop_server(@signature)` id but if I reconnect it , it gives me error of

```
/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
```

Here is the code

```
    $servers = {}
    EventMachine::run {
        [1,2,3].each do |port|
            $servers[:em_server_id] =  EventMachine::start_server "", port, EchoServer, port
            restart_server($servers[:em_server_id],port)
        end
    }

    def restart_server(s,port)
      EventMachine::stop_server(s)
      $servers[:em_server_id] = nil
      EventMachine::start_server "", port, EchoServer, port
    end
```

If i get better way sloving restart server that will also help else I need to stop and start servers again in that way only.

Comment: `$servers[:em_server_id] =  EventMachine::start_server "", port, EchoServer, port` is not doing what you think. Eventually, you have a hash `$servers` with just one key-value-pair (key: `:em_server_id`, value: `3`). Are you sure you want to do that?

Also, using EM.stop_server will take some time. It will return almost immediately, but the port will still be in use for a period of time. You might want to check whether the port is free with a simple TCPSocket using that port and checking for an error (or similar).